# Fire+Smoke Domain

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, smoke-simulation

This may just be a minor error but I cannot seem to get rid of the glow within the domain. I realize that in the Compositor, i copied the Attribute node from the Quick smoke and added an emission node to make the fire have some color. But I do not understand how to have the mesh/particle system emit without the domain cube containing it to look like the glowing box it does.[image: Fire/Smoke domain]

Comment: Plug the `flame` attribute into the emission strength.